# Pantheon Drupal + CiviCRM invoke() slow query, site is 504

Tags: drupal, pantheon

**Issue**

A civi donation form submission on our site did not go through this morning; user reported that the tab kept spinning.  As we tried to diagnose, the whole site went down with 504 errors.  We could not access frontend pages, nor backend pages in either the Drupal or CiviCRM install.  This was in the span of 2 hours or so.

I talked with Pantheon support and they showed that civicrm_invoke had gone awry / was frozen or slow.  The host restarted our services and the site went back up.  I can't reproduce and don't know why it happened.  I haven't found any info on this process causing issues for anyone else.

Looking through our logs, I believe this is the first / only time this has happened, but we want to make sure this absolutely does not happen again.

In our php slow logs this shows up as

```
[0x000000000462a988] run() /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:312
[0x000000000462a1c0] runItem() /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:86
[0x000000000462a058] _invoke() /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:54
[0x00000000046292c8] invoke() /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:484
[0x00007ffd903d5dc0] civicrm_invoke() unknown:0
```

This may correspond to the following error logged in our Drupal Watchdog log:

```
Type  civicrm
Date  Friday, January 6, 2017 - 12:42
User  Anonymous (not verified)
Location  /civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US?r=kh9Xk
Referrer  /support/donate-now
Message $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [message] => XML data could not be loaded. Make sure you specified the correct path. [code] => [exception] => Exception Object ( [message:protected] => XML data could not be loaded. Make sure you specified the correct path. [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/IDS/Filter/Storage.php [line:protected] => 220 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/IDS/Filter/Storage.php [line] => 111 [function] => getFilterFromXML [class] => IDS_Filter_Storage [type] => -> [args] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/IDS/Monitor.php [line] => 189 [function] => __construct [class] => IDS_Filter_Storage [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => IDS_Init Object ( [config] => Array ( [General] => Array ( [filter_type] => xml [filter_path] => /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/IDS/default_filter.xml [tmp_path] => /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/files/civicrm/upload/ [HTML_Purifier_Path] => IDS/vendors/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php [HTML_Purifier_Cache] => /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/files/civicrm/upload/ [scan_keys] => [exceptions] => Array ( [0] => __utmz [1] => __utmc [2] => widget_code [3] => html_message [4] => text_message [5] => body_html [6] => msg_html [7] => msg_text [8] => msg_subject [9] => description [10] => intro [11] => thankyou_text [12] => intro_text [13] => body_text [14] => footer_text [15] => thankyou_text [16] => tf_thankyou_text [17] => thankyou_footer [18] => thankyou_footer_text [19] => new_text [20] => renewal_text [21] => help_pre [22] => help_post [23] => confirm_title [24] => confirm_text [25] => confirm_footer_text [26] => confirm_email_text [27] => report_header [28] => report_footer [29] => data [30] => json [31] => instructions [32] => suggested_message [33] => page_text ) ) ) [configPath:IDS_Init:private] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/Config.IDS.ini ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/IDS.php [line] => 87 [function] => __construct [class] => IDS_Monitor [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [q] => civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US [r] => kh9Xk [IDS_request_uri] => /civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US?r=kh9Xk [IDS_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0 ) [1] => IDS_Init Object ( [config] => Array ( [General] => Array ( [filter_type] => xml [filter_path] => /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/IDS/default_filter.xml [tmp_path] => /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/files/civicrm/upload/ [HTML_Purifier_Path] => IDS/vendors/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php [HTML_Purifier_Cache] => /srv/bindings/4c07576353374fc8a0d2d5e79df205e8/files/civicrm/upload/ [scan_keys] => [exceptions] => Array ( [0] => __utmz [1] => __utmc [2] => widget_code [3] => html_message [4] => text_message [5] => body_html [6] => msg_html [7] => msg_text [8] => msg_subject [9] => description [10] => intro [11] => thankyou_text [12] => intro_text [13] => body_text [14] => footer_text [15] => thankyou_text [16] => tf_thankyou_text [17] => thankyou_footer [18] => thankyou_footer_text [19] => new_text [20] => renewal_text [21] => help_pre [22] => help_post [23] => confirm_title [24] => confirm_text [25] => confirm_footer_text [26] => confirm_email_text [27] => report_header [28] => report_footer [29] => data [30] => json [31] => instructions [32] => suggested_message [33] => page_text ) ) ) [configPath:IDS_Init:private] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/Config.IDS.ini ) ) ) [3] => Array ( [file] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php [line] => 139 [function] => check [class] => CRM_Core_IDS [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => civicrm [1] => ajax [2] => l10n-js [3] => en_US ) ) ) [4] => Array ( [file] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php [line] => 83 [function] => init [class] => CRM_Core_Invoke [type] => :: [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => civicrm [1] => ajax [2] => l10n-js [3] => en_US ) ) ) [5] => Array ( [file] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php [line] => 54 [function] => _invoke [class] => CRM_Core_Invoke [type] => :: [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => civicrm [1] => ajax [2] => l10n-js [3] => en_US ) ) ) [6] => Array ( [file] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module [line] => 484 [function] => invoke [class] => CRM_Core_Invoke [type] => :: [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => civicrm [1] => ajax [2] => l10n-js [3] => en_US ) ) ) [7] => Array ( [function] => civicrm_invoke [args] => Array ( [0] => ajax [1] => l10n-js [2] => en_US ) ) [8] => Array ( [file] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/includes/menu.inc [line] => 527 [function] => call_user_func_array [args] => Array ( [0] => civicrm_invoke [1] => Array ( [0] => ajax [1] => l10n-js [2] => en_US ) ) ) [9] => Array ( [file] => /srv/bindings/709ce589b8904430a0547eff7d72d2f9/code/index.php [line] => 21 [function] => menu_execute_active_handler [args] => Array ( ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => ) )
Severity  debug
Hostname  23.252.49.59
Operations
```

**Site Stats**

Pantheon hosted Drupal site with a CiviCRM integration.  Drupal 7.53, CiviCRM 4.6.22; these are the latest updates as of this post, and the rest of the site is currently updated.  CiviCRM came from the Pantheon-specific repo here: https://github.com/freeform/civicrm-drupal-pantheon.  CiviCRM requires extensive patching to work on Pantheon, and only the LTS (4.6.x) versions have Pantheon specific repos that are maintained.

I'm using the supporting modules CiviCRM Base Jumper, CiviCRM Cron, and CiviCRM Flush Caches patched as in https://www.drupal.org/node/2663684#comment-11856814.

**Thanks**

If anyone has experienced similar or has any insight, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/herbdool/civicrm-starterkit-drops-7/blob/master/profiles/civicrm_starterkit/civicrm_starterkit.make for potential patches (if you're not using CiviCRM Starterkit already).

Comment: You don't need CiviCRM Base Jumper any more.

Comment: I think the XML error you see has now been fixed in core since it's been implemented differently.